# SVN Integration with django

Tags: python, django, svn

I have a small bug tracker written in django.  I'd like to integrate it with an svn repository so that when someone commits to svn it will automatically add a note to an issue in the bug tracker.  Does anyone have any input on how to best approach this?  Should I setup svn hooks?  use a cron job and pull from the log?

Comment: I would use post commit hooks myself unless you specifically dont want it to be realtime...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have a post-commit hook in the svn repo that uses, ideally, a restful interface to your Django app and adds the note. That way your app remains very simple.